# Yii 2: can not use @web in config/web.php file aliases section

Tags: yii2

I am using basic-template.

here is my code in `config/web.php`:

```
return [
    'aliases' => [
        '@uploadUrl' => '@web/uploads/',
    ],
];
```

I want to use the alias like this:

```
<?= Html::img( Yii::getAlias('@uploadUrl/'.$model->image)); ?>
```

But, program erred:

> Invalid path alias: @web/uploads/

thanks for help!

Comment: You are using an alias to create an alias. Not sure that works. Try defining the '@uploadUrl' without '@web'

Comment: Yes, It works without `@web`; As the same, I defined another alias `'@uploadDir' => '@app\web\uploads'`, and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have an install to test ATM, [but the examples](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html) never end in a slash character. You could try removing that after uploads/
Also you could try something like this and see if it works.

```
Yii::setAlias('@uploadUrl', '@web/uploads');
```

Comment: Yes, I tried before asking question. doing this has no difference.

Comment: Can you do the following:
<?= Yii::getAlias('@web') ?>
and check what that prints, and see if your uploads folder is in the correct spot?

Comment: Maybe this is a bug ? [issue in github.yii2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/929).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'@uploadUrl' => '@app/web/uploads',
```

Comment: Of course I used this for saving uploaded file. It  worked well.

Comment: Ok. Next way. Create from config folder file `aliases.php`.  Put this `<?php  
Yii::setAlias('web', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/web');`  And in `/web/index.php` put this `require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/aliases.php');` after this `require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');`

Comment: Here is Yii 2 framework 's define for @web: ` Yii::setAlias('@web', $request->getBaseUrl());`; and the `@uploadDir` I use for accessing uploaded file via url, so defined like this `dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/web'`  is not satisfy me.

Comment: Yes, I really tried `@webroot`, unfortunately, It did not work either.   Please notice the alias setting place: I set it in `@app/config/web.php`, not in a controller or model or view file.